# Redirect http request to ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

My app has a modal sign in form that I display using ajax:

```
<% if !current_user %>
  <%= link_to "Sign in", signin_path, remote: true %>
<% end %>
```

**routes.rb**

```
get 'signin', to: 'static_pages#signin', as: 'signin'
```

**static_pages_controller.rb**

```
def signin
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render :action => 'signin.js.erb' }
    format.js   { render :action => 'signin.js.erb' }
  end     
end
```

**signin.js.erb**

```
$('#modalPlaceholder').html("<%= j render(partial: '/static_pages/signin') %>");
$('#modalPlaceholder').show();
```

This works well.

I would now like to intercept actions that require user sign in and display this modal. In my application controller I have:

**application_controller.rb**

```
def require_signin!
  if current_user.nil?
    render :action => '../static_pages/signin.js.erb'
  end
end
helper_method :require_signin!
```

This works when the originating action is remote: :true and rails simply redirects it however when the originating action is a standard request the action is intercepted correctly by the application controller however the modal is displayed on screen in raw html and not loaded correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can check format type of request and render for it.

```
def require_signin!
  if current_user.nil?
    if request.format.html?
       #html render file here
    else
       render :action => '../static_pages/signin.js.erb'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes, however regardless of request format I want the action to be handled as js as per static_pages_controller.rb above.